# How to use multivariate chain rule and table of values to find partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I don't know what the first thing I should do for this question is. How can the principles of the multivariate form of the chain rule be applied to solve this question? Thanks.
I am trying using this version of the chain rule
[image]

[image]

Comment: The first thing you should do is write down the chain rule.  Can you get that far?

Comment: yes I can see the formula for the chain rule but I don't know how to apply it

Comment: Can you post what you have done, and indicate where the difficulty is?  What formula for the chain rule are you trying to use?

Comment: I haven't done any work because I don't know where to start. I was advised to decompose f(e^u+sin(v), e^u+cos(v)) into x = e^u + sin(v) and y = e^u + cos(v) I have edited the question to include the version of the chain rule I am using

Comment: I'll write answer to try to help you.  I'm a slow typist.  It will be a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to understand how the chain rule applies to your problem.  As the problem indicates you have $x=e^u + \sin v, y = e^u + \cos v.$  Where does that fit into the chain rule formula?  (The unfortunate thing with this statement of the chain rule is that $u$ means different things on the two sides of the equation.  On the left-hand side it means $g,$ and on the right-hand side, it means $f$.  This isn't a peculiarity of the chain rule for several variables.  The chain rule in one variable also exhibits this phenomenon.)

Anyway, on the left-hand side, $u$ means $g$ and $t_i$ is one of the variables we're differentiating with respect to: say $u$. Then on the right-hand side, $u$ means $f,$ and the $x_i$ are the variables in the definition of $f$.  So we can take $x_1 = x, x_2 = y$.  That gives us:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$
We get a completely similar equation for the derivative with resect to $v$.

I now you have to calculate the partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ and substitute into the formulas above.

Just in case, I'll mention that in the problem $g_u,$ for example, means $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}.$

Try it now.

Comment: How did you know that "on the right-hand side, u means f"?

Additionally, how can we calculate ∂f/∂x and ∂f∂y without an explicit definition for f?

Comment: It's just like the chain rule for functions of a single variable.  When you write $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$ on the left-hand side, $y$ is a function $f\circ g.$  On the right-hand side, $y=f.$

Comment: Thank you for the help but I may need to take a step back for a while. I will mark this as answered since most other people with a similar question would probably have understood the process by now

Comment: Sure.  If you still have problems, just ask another question.  You need to do two things.  You need to relate the symbols $f_x, g_u$ etc. to the symbols in the chain rule formula.  Then you have to decide whether you want to use the values at $(0,0)$ or at $(1,2).$  I'll just say that it's completely analogous to the way you do it with one variable.